# How to set desired return type in match structure?

Tags: rust, match, serde-json

In the example in the crate documentation of serde_json (parse JSON into a Rust struct), error handling is omitted:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::Result;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
    phones: Vec<String>,
}

fn typed_example() -> Result<()> {
    // Some JSON input data as a &str. Maybe this comes from the user.
    let data = r#"
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "age": 43,
            "phones": [
                "+44 1234567",
                "+44 2345678"
            ]
        }"#;

    // Parse the string of data into a Person object. This is exactly the
    // same function as the one that produced serde_json::Value above, but
    // now we are asking it for a Person as output.
    let p: Person = serde_json::from_str(data)?;

    // Do things just like with any other Rust data structure.
    println!("Please call {} at the number {}", p.name, p.phones[0]);

    Ok(())
}
```

What `from_string()` does is controlled by the type of the **target** of the assignment.

In practice, we have to handle the error. So, the natural thing to do is:

```
match p: Person = serde_json::from_str(data) {
    // ...
}
```

but that is not allowed in match structure.

```
match serde_json::from_str(data) {
    // ...
}
```

returns always an empty type "()".

My situation involves many nested match structures, so I would not like to use the obvious solution of assigning to a variable first.

How do I control the desired target type of expression in the match structure?

Comment: That's not how you write a match statement. It should look much more like the regular assignment. `let p: Person = match ...`

Answer (score 7):

In the example you give, error handling is deferred to the caller:

```
let p: Person = serde_json::from_str(data)?;
```

Notice the `?` at the end: it means that in case of error, the function should return immediately propagating the error.

If you want to handle the error locally, you need to use `match`, but you can't do `match p: Person = serde_json::from_str(data) { /* ... */ }` because `from_str` doesn't return a `Person`. What you need to do is:

```
let p: Person = match serde_json::from_str (data) {
   Ok (p) => p,
   Err (_) => Person { name: "John Doe".into(), age: 42, phones: vec![] },
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Herohtar, the syntax `match p: Person = serde_json::from_str(data) { /* ... */ }` is invalid, but you can do

```rust
let p: Person = match serde_json::from_str(data)? {
    // ...
}
```

Another option is turbofish:

```rust
let p = match serde_json::from_str::<Person>(data)? {
    // ...
}
```